# How to format app engine yaml file for referencing google maps external javascript file

Tags: php, google-app-engine, yaml

I have a php file, a part of which echos out some html and javascript including an src tag for a google maps api script. In an ordinary php environment this works ok and places the google map into the page. With the app engine when I use the launcher to view the result the explanation mark shows up and doesn't allow me to view the page.  There are no problems when I don't try to echo out any javascript so I know the formatting of the yaml file is the problem.

In short I have no idea how to format the yaml file for this situation.

Like so..

```
echo '

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" 
       src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
</head> 
<body>
<div id="map" style="width: 900px; height: 700px">
</div> 

etc...
';  // end echo
```

Reading the app engine documentation on yaml files it's not clear to me whether or not it's possible to echo out urls via an src when using app engine.  All the notes I've read seem to indicate that the scripts have to go in a separate static directory within the yaml folder but how do I just refer to a javascript file url on another server ?

The documentation seems incredibly complicated for what previously was simply a matter of echoing the javascript.  I've lost track of the number of variations that I've made to the yaml file to get it to conform to the way I'm supposed to format it but i cant find any clear instructions on how to do it.
Could somebody who knows about this please give me some guidance.  I'd be really grateful.

Comment: Apart from sending the echo value to the browser, app engine does not do anything with it, like in "normal" php environments. Therefore there is no need to reference google maps api script in your app.yaml, as it is an external script, not directly part of your app. If you are getting an exclamation mark in your browser, then there is likely a different error. Is anything being shown in the App Engine logs?

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply and apologies for my delay in answering.  You are correct and I very much appreciate the information you provided.  I did try the yaml file without any reference to the api script before and still had errors which appeared (to me) to be related to the script reference but I was wrong. In view of what you said however I started from scratch and used the simplest yaml file I could and it works now ok.  I'm really not sure what formatting I got wrong but I'm just glad that there is no need reference external files.  Thank you very much again for the info.